# Schwinn Spirit Trailer - Bearing Repair

Tags: bearings, trailer

I bought a used Schwinn Spirit trailer and have converted it into a flatbed to use on a self-supported tour. I'm working on the wheels right now, but I am having trouble removing the old sealed bearings. They are old and gunked up, so they don't roll as well as I'd like. I was able to remove the snap ring retainer and the axle, but after whacking on the bearings for a bit, they won't budge. How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a photo or two?  I'm unfamiliar with that trailer.  Does it have wheelchair stub axles or something else?

Comment: Are you using a [long drive punch](http://cdn3.volusion.com/afdbs.sdunm/v/vspfiles/photos/PLT5.NP-VP-2.jpg?1442928105) and a ball peen hammer from the backside to tap the bearings out? You will want to go slow, and work all around the bearing seat.  Do not try to pound out just one side of the bearing, that won't work.  Do note, this will be destructive.  No way should you plan on using the removed bearings again.

Comment: Back when I had a bike with cartridge bearings I had a tool designed to assist bearing removal.  It was a "bobby pin" spring with two metal semicircles attached to the two ends.  You'd squeeze it and insert into the bearing, then use a drift punch from the other side to drive the bearing out.  The above setup appears to be identical to what I had.

Comment: I was using a spare bolt and a rubber mallet. I'll probably end up dropping by my LBS and having them do it for me rather than buying new tools. Thx.

Comment: Rubber mallet?  Borrow a decent steel hammer. The rubber mallet definitely won't work for that job.   And I'm guessing the price of the tools will be half of the service charge at the bike shop.